# Git bash, using VIM 8.1 on Windows :Term command. Node REPL not working correctly

Tags: node.js, vim, terminal, git-bash, mintty

I'm working on a corporate network (windows pc) with little access to tools like tmux, cmder etc.. however after recent update to git bash, we have access to Vim v8.1 which has a terminal built in.

I can load up **vim** and the type **:term** to load up a terminal... it works for standard terminal operations such as **ls** or **git push** etc.. but when you run node it seems to crash. And it doesn't render the node repl prompt.

Anyone know how I can get this working? (As predicted it works on the mac)... this is really useful to test out an algorithm quickly without leaving vim.

I also tried just typing !node to execute outside of vim and this has the same effect.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Many thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

You just type `node -i` for interactive (This isn't needed on the vim 8.1 on the mac)